# VisualStudio 2022 React+Asp.Net in 'import' enable Itellisense for all files in the folder (scss, css, etc)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I need in .jsx(.js) files when writing "import './some..... ' " so that a hint about all files in the folder appears here as it works in VS Code. I've seen a solution somewhere before, but now I can't find it.

It seems there you have to add a jsconfig.json file with parameters. I tried, but 'scss' and 'css' files don't show up in the tooltip.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you mean autocomplete path, I didn't find a related extension, could you please clarify your question>

Comment: For example in VS Code when in .js file I type 'import "./...etc"' I see in ToolTip (autocomplete, intellisense) all files in the folder including .css, .scss.
In VisualStudio in a project like React+Asp.Net when I type import "./...etc" I don't see files with css and scss extension in ToolTip (autocomplete, intellisense)

Comment: @proa I checked in the marketplace, it looks no related extension there.